# WebSocket Error in Eclipse using tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, websocket

I tried to deploy a websocket application using Tomcat 7.0 in Eclipse. 
After i deployed the app on localhost, when i try to access the websocket it throws an error like this

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:8080/GroupChatServer/chat?name=hari' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I deployed the app in 
http://localhost:8080/GroupChatServer/

I tried a sample chat app from this link: 
[GroupChatServer](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/)

can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Please include any relevant code and configuration.

Comment: The code is too larges, so i attached a link for the code and method i followed in the link.  @ryanyuyu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide enough details to answer the question absolutely.

But i had a similar problem

The Error during the handshake happens, because Tomcat has its own api for websockets. Thus you might have added the JSR implementation or something similar as javax.websocket-api in your pom.xml there comes a conflict at runtime.

Try to not export your Websocket-library to your webserver, thus it uses its own implementation.

If you use maven, set the websocket dependency as provided:

```
    <!-- Provided Websocket API, because tomcat has its own implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but this did not fix it for me, I added provided scope to java.websocket and also javaee-api, because that has its own implementation of websocket, but still no joy. I am running tomcat 8 on a centos7 server, and it works on my local machine